# CodeQL in Github action: Abort the workflow if somehing was found

Tags: github-actions, codeql

I'm having a GH-action which checks out source code, builds it, codeQL-checks it (+uploads the sarif results) and then publishes the built artifact to artifactory.

Hoewever, I would need to abort the publishing to our repo if there were vulnerabilities found by the github/codeql-action/analyze@v2 job. Only push if everything is ok.

Is this possible?
Any way to access the scanning results inside the same running action workflow?

Comment: Can you simply not check the output file and decide on the basis of its contents before uploading?

Comment: @Azeem That's what I want to achieve, I need to somehow know about the results of the analysis before uploading

Comment: Looks like SARIF is similar to JSON. You can use `jq` to check the results and then make decisions accordingly. If you have a sample SARIF file with vulnerabilities, please include that in your question. See [SARIF support for code scanning](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/code-scanning/integrating-with-code-scanning/sarif-support-for-code-scanning).

Answer (score 0):

As [CodeQL documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/code-scanning/automatically-scanning-your-code-for-vulnerabilities-and-errors/customizing-code-scanning#defining-the-severities-causing-pull-request-check-failure) states:

> By default, only alerts with the severity level of `Error` or security severity level of `Critical` or `High` will cause a pull request check failure.

You can configure your repository settings to fail on security alerts with the severity of `Medium`

[image: repo settings]

Then scroll down to `Pull request check failure` under `Protection rules`:

[image: Pull request check failure]

Then set the levels you want

[image: severity levels]

See more:

- https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/code-scanning/automatically-scanning-your-code-for-vulnerabilities-and-errors/about-code-scanning-alerts#about-alert-details
- https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/code-scanning/automatically-scanning-your-code-for-vulnerabilities-and-errors/customizing-code-scanning#defining-the-severities-causing-pull-request-check-failure

Comment: Thank you for the hint about severity! Though I am here not talking about Pull Requests, but really checking the results inside the GH-action workflow. I guess this is not possible?